# How to use letter keys in turtle?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use other keys such w a s d  in turtle besides the arrow keys for commands?
Can I make the turtle move by using the (w a s d) keys?
or can i use the "A" key to run  turtle.penup() != turtle.penup()

Comment: what did you try? Even documentation for Turtle mentions char `"a"` as example in `onkey()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `"a"` to run command - even documentation for `onkey()` mentions char `"a"` as example

```
import turtle

def forward():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(100)

def backward():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(100)

def left():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.forward(100)

def right():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(100)

turtle.onkey(forward, 'w')
turtle.onkey(backward, 's')
turtle.onkey(left, 'a')
turtle.onkey(right, 'd')

turtle.listen()

#turtle.mainloop()
turtle.exitonclick()
```